# Downloading iOS Nest Sample Project

Tags: download, nest-api

Following the link for the sample iOS project, I am unable to download the project files to run under XCode. Please advise what the procedure is to access the sample code. Saving the links to Downloads folder does not download the actual files. Thanks, D.J.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a big part of what makes our community tick. These guidelines are important and I suggest you read them over. As of right now, unless you can make your question more programming-orientated, your question is better suited for another Stack Exchange, i.e., Super User.

Comment: Adding to what Luxelin said, you should actually provide the link you're referring to. Are you not able to download the code or are you not able to open it after you have it downloaded to your computer? Is XCode giving you an error? When you ask a question, give as much information as possible so we can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you mean the [iOS-NestDK](https://github.com/nestlabs/iOS-NestDK) sample project. (embedded in the [iOS-NestDK](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/ios-nestdk) sample code doc)

To download the project, click the 'Download ZIP' button from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nestlabs/iOS-NestDK), then open the project file in Xcode.